# Spring: Azure Feature Manager Feature toggles Microsoft.Targeting bean not found

Tags: spring, azure, kotlin, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-azure

I am currently having a problem with the Azure feature manager. I used the following tutorial to add a feature toggle to my application: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-feature-flag-spring-boot)

This is working fine as long as we are talking about a manually set feature flag. As soon as the type of the feature is set to "Targeting" in Azure, the following code will result in an error.

```
featureManager.isEnabledAsync(FeatureToggle.OUR_FEATURE_TARGETING.key).block()
```

Specifically we will get `No bean named 'Microsoft.Targeting' available` in the spring error log. A client trying to acces an endpoint containing the above code will get a 500 with the error message `Fail fast is set and a Filter was unable to be found: Microsoft.Targeting`

---

Additional info

I am using Kotlin and Spring.

Setting the feature to "Time Based" will result in an error aswell.

The service calling the feature manager looks like this

```
@Autowired
private lateinit var featureManager: FeatureManager

fun feature(): String {
        if (featureManager.isEnabledAsync(FeatureToggle.OUR_FEATURE_TARGETING.key).block() == true) {
            return "feature A!"
        } else {
            return "feature B!"
        }
```

And the FeatureToggle Enum looks like this

```
enum class FeatureToggle(val key: String) {
    OUR_FEATURE_TARGETING("feature")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't go over it in that guide, but the built in Feature Flags are not configured to be on by default, then need to be built in an `@Configuration` file. More info can be found here https://microsoft.github.io/spring-cloud-azure/docs/azure-app-configuration/2.3.0/reference/html/index.html#built-in-feature-filters